# Site wide font differs when deployed on google cloud platform vs local server

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-cloud-platform, pug

I am running a `node.js` website with some square space templates. On my local server it looks as expected on chrome:

[image: local.png]

However when deploye using `glcoud app deploy` I am seeing the font is much fatter, and the `|` bar in between the font is much shorter

[image: deployed.png]

This is true for Chrome and Safari. The public site is hosted here: https://lingxiaoling-us.appspot.com/

Additionally, the site looks fine on mobile:

[image: mobile.png]

With the exception that the central `Art | Blog | Code | __` disappears as soon as it appears on mobile, which is a separate problem in so far as I understand.

I cannot even begin to figure out what is wrong, the logical thing is to reproduce the error on my local machine by, ie removing certain `css` files. I have been doing this with no results. Does someone with more experience see an immediate source of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it looks like now
[image: This is how it looks like now]

When you unclick the font it looks like you wanted
[image: When you unclick the font it looks like you wanted]

You have duplicated fonts on the same css styling:

```
.collection-nav-desc-wrapper .collection-desc p {
color: #e1483d;
font-family: Georgia, serif;
font-size: 36px;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: italic;
letter-spacing: 0px;
line-height: 1.2em;
font-family: adobe-garamond-pro; <------- This one is taking precedence over the Georgia Family
font-size: 120px;
font-weight: 600;
font-style: normal;
letter-spacing: -.01em;
line-height: 1.3em;
text-transform: none;
text-decoration: none;
```

Comment: omg how did you find that?? I don't know the first thing about webfonts thb, what's your suggestion for a fix?  @Horacio Coronel

Comment: Check the images, it's the 22406 of your squarespace.css file

Comment: ok @Horacio Coronel I commented out the line `adobe-garamond-pro` in `squarespace.css`, and redeployed the app.However it still behaves as before.

Comment: I just took a look at the code again, and I still see the font property twice in the `.collection-nav-desc-wrapper .collection-desc p` Maybe the css didn't get upload, or somehow it managed to stay there. the problem Is that you have two times the same property and CSS work they way downwards like a waterfall, so your first `font-family` property has `Georgia, serif`but later comes the second `font-family` and your original one gets overridden with `adobe-garamond-pro` I hope this helps.

Comment: It's strange because I think the font I want is actually `adobe-garamond-pro`. Because when I change all the `adobe-...` font in my `css` to `Georgia, serif`, I reproduce the error on my local server. However, changing all the `Georgia, serif` into `adobe-...` and deploying on remote does not fix the problem

Comment: I just checked it, and now I see it with the right font you wanted to use. Have you tried browsing on a private browser?

Comment: weird because I still see this: https://i.imgur.com/IejdQ2Z.png. And yeah it looks the same on a private browser , and safari/safari private mode.  Although it looks fine on iphone and has always looked fine.

Comment: evidently garamond is not a "web-safe" font (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403696/is-garamond-really-a-web-safe-font). However it loads fine for my squarespace-hosted site(https://lingxiaoling.me/), so maybe they're doing something differently?